# this keyword inside a using block in C#

Tags: c#, using-statement

What does `this` refer to inside of a `using` block in C#?

Comment: Well I already answered the other 2 as well :\

Comment: cut out the following part which has being answered below.

"Since we're on this what are defined as unmanaged resources? Does a normal file read fall in to this? "

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` inside of a `using` block refers to the same thing as `this` outside of a `using` block: the current instance of the class.

A `using` block should be used with all classes that implement the IDisposable interface. It's an implementation detail of the class if it wraps managed and/or unmanaged resources.

Comment: +1 However, "...should be used with all [Disposable] classes..." has some strings attached. `using` really only works when the object lifetime can be controlled from a single scope (that "can work down the call-stack") and there are some cases when it's not appropriate or applicable.

Comment: @pst: Scope of `using` block marked with a `{`,`}` symbols, and scope of a this "pointer" is the same of a scope of an application

Answer (score 2):

1 - this always refers to the object scope you are currently in for example

```
void myFunc(int sameName)
{
    this.sameName += sameName;
}
```

in this case this.sameName refers to the classes variable called sameName while the one without the this qualifier refers to the local variables (use in case you have local/globals with the same name or for clarity).

2 - Unmanaged resources are sockets, httpservers, connections, filebuffers, etc.... Anything that is IDisposable (that isn't automatically GC'ed like persistent connections or some GUI elements like Modeless forms etc...)

3 - technically yes, if you don't explicity call File.Close() or place it within a using statement then the changes you made to the file may not get flushed back to disc so if you have a file buffer open you should always call Close() on it.

EDIT: You can ignore 2 and 3 since he removed them from the question but I'll leave them here just in case